# Can't get my matplotlib text to refresh on pick_event

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, onclicklistener, interaction, bubble-chart

Please help take a look at this piece of Python code and see if there's anything wrong with it. I can't seem to get my text refreshed to show the county name according to the bubble I click on. I have attached an image of how the chart would look like. Thanks! :)

*Note: Thanks Trenton for reminding. I have edited this question to include a reproducible data frame of random numbers for reference.*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

county = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

np.random.seed(444)
x_data = list(np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, 26))
y_data = list(np.random.gamma(2, 1, 26)/10)
pop = list(np.random.randint(10000, 500000, 26))

data = pd.DataFrame({'county': county, 'x': x_data, 'y': y_data, 'population': pop})

c1 = 'blue' #blue
c2 = 'red' #red
n = len(data['x'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
chart = plt.scatter(data['x']*100, 
                    data['y']*100, 
                    c=data['y'], 
                    cmap='RdBu',
                    s=np.sqrt(data['population']/np.pi), 
                    alpha=.5,
                    picker=5)
plt.gca().set_facecolor('gainsboro')
plt.gca().set_ylabel('Y value, in %', fontsize=12)
plt.gca().set_xlabel('X value, in %', fontsize=12)
plt.gca().set_xlim(0,8)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0,70)
plt.gca().set_axisbelow(True)
plt.gca().grid(color='lightgrey')

cbar = fig.colorbar(chart)
cbar.set_ticks([0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['30%', '40%', '50%','60%','70%','80%'])
    
t = ax.text(1, 75, 'Selected county:', fontsize=12)

def onpick(event):
    county = data.iloc[event.ind[0]]['county']
    t.set_text(1, 75, 'Selected county: {} County'.format(county), fontsize=12)
        

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Current chart output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPwhz.png

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney, appreciate the pointers. I have added a reproducible example data frame for the code and an image of the current output. There isn't any errors, and the expected output is for the name of county displayed on the top left corner of the plot when each scatter plot point is clicked on. :)